# Ordering XMLDocument.SelectNodes results

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML which I want to order by priority.  Don't fancy using XPath and thought LINQ might work but I get an argument exception thrown with the message "At least one object must implement IComparable."

Can I order the results somehow?

```
<Root>
  <Item>
    <Priority><![CDATA[4]]</Priority>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Priority><![CDATA[1]]</Priority>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Priority><![CDATA[3]]</Priority>
   </Item>
</Root>

var result = doc.SelectNodes("//Item");
var ordered = ddddd.Cast<XmlNode>().OrderBy(x => x.SelectSingleNode("Priority"));  //EXCEPTION!!!
```

Comment: why u have Loading_Priority when its Priority.. was that intentional...or mistake..And what's the Exception..can you show stack trace

Comment: Are we supposed to magically guess which exception you are talking about?

Comment: Have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `x => x.SelectSingleNode("Priority")` to `x => x.SelectSingleNode("Priority").InnerText`

Oh, and remember, that you will compare strings, not ints, that way.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the exception. Just discovered that XML has CDATA in it so have updated my question